# oracle 11g Personal Edition: Create Schema

Tags: oracle, schema

This is a two-part question. I have installed an Oracle 11g Personal Edition Server on a Windows Server 2008 VM. During the installation I chose the option to install a database as well (sample/blank database?).

Now, on the VM, I can launch the Oracle Enterprise Manager Console at localhost port 1158, login as either SYSMAN or SYSTEM and in that I can see: 'Database Instance': orcl.127.55.199 . I can also see 'OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener' in the Services control panel in running state.

1) I need to be able to create a new Schema in the default database. How do I do that using the Oracle Enterprise Manager or anything else?

2) How can connect to that schema from another computer, say a Windows 7 workstation? I am able to see the VM running the Oracle server and I am even able to make a connection but I get an error like '12541 no listener'. I am pretty sure I have the Oracle client software installed. Do I need to create a TNS file? I am using Direct Connection.

Thanks!

Comment: I think in the oracle world, schema  = user.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I create the Schema for, say, a 'gisclient' user? I don't even know how to create a new user using the Oracle Enterprise Manager.

Comment: I can create users but still other things are needed. thx

Answer (score 1):

Never mind:
I got this all to work. Here are some brief notes:

1) Used Oracle Database Configuration Assistant (ODCA) to create a database

2) Used Oracle NET Manager to Create a Listener

3) Restarted Oracle Listener Service

4) Used Oracle Enterprise Manager in localhost environment to create Users--which seem to be the same as Schema--thanks @Leo for your input in the Comments!

Everything works now!

Hope this helps someone.